# Google Appengine Datastore I want to add primary_key

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a ndb model and I use Python + google appengine. I want to add primary key to my first field "name". Forexample I added a name "Ada", after that if I want to add again "Ada", it mustnt add, it gives me an error. I can do it easily with django but I couldnt figure out with google appengine. Can you show me a solution way please. Here is my codes:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=False)
    created_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://squeeville.com/2009/01/30/add-a-unique-constraint-to-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`get_or_insert()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_get_or_insert) which will add a named key to your entity.

So if your username is `name = 'Ada'` you could do something like this:

```
 user_db = User.get_or_insert(name.lower(), username=name)
```

The first parameter is the `key_name` and I used the `lower()` function just to make sure that they will be consistent and somebody with a name `'ADA'` wouldn't be able to create a new entity, unless you want that.

Comment: I am getting this error : Expected string, got User(key=Key('User', 'ada') :/

Comment: well.. you have to provide a string as first argument to the get_or_insert function of the User.. check what I'm doing again and follow the link that I posted..

Comment: This is not my solution.